# Performance comparison of “patternnet” and “newff” for binary classification in MATLAB R2014a

Tags: classification, matlab, neural-networks, sensitivity-specificity

I have a binary classification problem for financial ratios and variables. When I use `newff` (with `trainlm` and `mse` and threshold of 0.5 for output) I have a high classification accuracy (5-fold cross validation – near 89-92%) but when I use `patternnet` (`trainscg` with `crossentropy`) my accuracy is 10% lower than `newff`. (I normalized data before insert it to network - `mapminmax` or `mapstd`)

When I use these models for out-sample data (for current year- created models designed based one previous year(s) data sets) I have better classification accuracies in `patternnet` with better sensitivity and specificity. For example I have these results in my problem:

## Newff:

Accuracy: 92.8% sensitivity: 94.08% specificity: 91.62%

Out sample results: accuracy: 60% sensitivity: 48% and specificity: 65.57%

## Patternnet:

Accuracy: 73.31% sensitivity: 69.85% specificity: 76.77%

Out sample results: accuracy: 70% sensitivity: 62.79% and specificity: 73.77%

Why we have these differences between `newff` and `patternent`. Which model should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid posting the same question on different StacKExchange forums ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649621/performance-comparison-of-patternnet-and-newff-for-binary-classification-in ); if the question is deemed out-of-context it will be transfered by our moderators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On face value I would recommend using `patternnet` as it gives you better out of sample performance; the results from `newff` seems suspiciously good leading me to believe some over-fitting occurs. On that matter check the following link: [Improve Neural Network Generalization and Avoid Overfitting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/improve-neural-network-generalization-and-avoid-overfitting.html).

To comment on the different results: For `newff` a Levenberg-Marquardt backpropagation is utilized while for `patternnet`, scaled conjugate gradient backpropagation. In general, different optimization procedures are not guaranteed to arrive in the same result even if they had the target function to optimize against. In your case through you are also using different target functions (`mse` and `crossentropy` respectively). It would probably be alarming you if did got the same results as you are fitting different criteria. :)

Having said that, using `newff` seems a bit odd. It is considered obsolete since R2010b and you are recommend (by the docs) to use `feedforwardnet`. Try using `feeforwardnet` first and then decide on which procedure you will ultimately use. As it stands it seems like you comparing the performance of a function (`newff`) people have not worked on for at least 4 years (if not more) against the performance of a function (`patternnet`) that is actively developed. It is not really surprising that the latter one it does a better job.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I added another question in above main question. I checked with `Patternnet` but have the same problem. (I think there isn’t any difference between structures of `newff` and `patternent` in designing network but `patternnet` is newer function so I must use it). I’m using early stopping in every structure, so besides using early stopping why I have over-fitting? My system structure mentioned above. thanks.

Comment: As mentioned because different fitting criteria are used, the same network structure will almost certainly be optimized for different tasks. And it is not necessary you get a 95%+ classification success in any case for your out-of-sample predictions. Finally, it might also be the case that your training sample is not a good approximation of your population. So while doing a good initial training, the network has not learned "enough" true populations characteristics. (Ah! And you can always experiment with different transfer functions; currently you are using `tansig` in both cases I guess.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. what's your idea about my second question (PS. in main question that added today)? optimization algorithm etc.

Comment: Bayesian regularization in NN's is far from my area of expertise, I am sorry. I think it will probably worth your time starting a new question about it. It does have a significant statistical context so I believe you will be able to get some good answers. As a general suggestion: Try not to pack a lot of different questions in one thread because it is harder to draw people's attention to it as well as makes it harder for someone in future to guess what the context of a thread is.